# Улов в количестве одной единицы

Tags: значение-слов

Можно ли назвать уловом всего одну пойманную жертву?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Можно.**
Второе значение слова 'улов' по БТС:

> Количество пойманной добычи (рыбы, птицы, зверя).

Нижняя граница количества не оговаривается, так что единица вполне входит в это определение.